# In program wipe, what does the number in parentheses mean?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

In program `wipe`, what does the number in parentheses, after the pass number, mean?

[image: program wipe]

I've read through the man page several times and cannot find an explanation.

[Manual page for `wipe`](https://die.net/man/1/wipe)